# How to create a button with dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, html

whenever i clicked a **SEND BUTTON**  a dropdown menu will popup. How can I do it? That's my code right now. What's wrong with this snippet?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["driver_number"]))?>
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="driver_number">
  <option value="Driver Number">Driver Number</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
 <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="if(!confirm('+ document.getElementById('driver_number').value')){return false;}" >Send</button> </form>
```

UPDATE: Thank you guys! All your answer help me.

Comment: What code have you written to add the dropdown menu?

Comment: Are you talking about your select element being the drop down menu? If that's the case then normally you would check if the value of your select has been sent before before you submit the form and if not communicate it to the user via error message (i.e. basic form validation) which can include setting focus on the select element that will automatically expand it to show options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do following changes:

1) You are selecting element by id so need to give id to your select box

2) Your escaping for click event in incorrect change your code as below

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="driver_number" id="driver_number">
  <option value="Driver Number">Driver Number</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
 <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="if(!confirm(document.getElementById('driver_number').value)){return false;}" >Send</button> </form>
```

Comment: thats not what I want to happen bro. I want my dropdown is INSIDE my button. The dropdown will popup if i click the button

Answer (score 0):

Please see my complete runable code . I hope it will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<div class="container">
<?php if(isset($_POST["driver_number"]))
print_r($_POST);
?>
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->

  <button type="button"  style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDropdown">Send dropdown value</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myDropdown" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;   </button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
       <form action="#" method="post">
<select name="driver_number">
 <option value="Driver Number">Driver Number</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
    <button type="submit" input style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="if(!confirm('+ document.getElementById('driver_number').value')){return false;}" >Send</button>
   </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to change the button `type="submit"` to `type="button"`, otherwise the form is submitted without evaluating the onclick event.

Secondly, to use `document.getElementById('driver_'number')` you  must have an id on the select element.

Thirdly (this is mainly for elegance) the `{return false;}` in the `if` condition for the `confirm` could be unnecessary, and you could implement the submission in a function as suggest in the code below:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["driver_number"])) { print_r($_POST); }// to test what has been posted?>
<form id="myform" action="#" method="post">
<select id="driver_number" name="driver_number">
  <option value="Driver Number">Driver Number</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
 <button type="button" input style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:black" name="submitSent" class="btn btn-primary"onclick="send();" >Send</button> </form>

<script>
function send(){ if(confirm(document.getElementById('driver_number').value)){ document.getElementById('myform').submit(); }
}

</script>
```

Finally, there are two typos `'+`  and `'` in your `if(!confirm('+ document.getElementById('driver_number').value'))` condition, it should read `if(!confirm(document.getElementById('driver_number').value))`